# React-query persist client with typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I was trying to use the PersistQueryClientProvider, but it's throwing an error of type "declaring missing parameters on the queryClient". However, in the documentation, these parameters are stated as optional. Here are the errors:

```
Type 'QueryClient' is missing the following properties from type 'QueryClient': logger, mountCount, ensureQueryData, getLogger ts(2739)
QueryClientProvider.d.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'client' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PersistQueryClientProviderProps'
```

and the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query"
import { PersistQueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query-persist-client'
import { createSyncStoragePersister } from '@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister'

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  },
})

const persister = createSyncStoragePersister({
  storage: window.localStorage,
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PersistQueryClientProvider client={queryClient} persistOptions={{ persister }}>
        <App />
      </PersistQueryClientProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and for information the version of the packages:

```
{
  "name": "template-vite-react-ts-tailwind-v3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister": "^4.32.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-persist-client": "^4.32.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.13.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-router": "^6.14.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "@types/react-query": "^1.2.9",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "vitawind": "^2.2.4",
    "vite": "^2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Why is this error occurring? And how can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message:

```bash
Type 'QueryClient' is missing the following properties from type 'QueryClient': logger, mountCount, ensureQueryData, getLogger ts(2739)
QueryClientProvider.d.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'client' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PersistQueryClientProviderProps'
```

means that the `QueryClient` type required by `PersistQueryClientProvider` does not match the type of the query client created in:

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  ...
})
```

This is because the `QueryClient` exported from *"react-query"* is [an older version of the library (v3)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query); the `PersistQueryClientProvider` requires the `QueryClient` from [v4 of react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/quick-start).

To fix the error, you'll need to [install v4 of react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/installation) and use the `QueryClient` exported from there.

*1. install v4 of react query:*

```bash
npm i @tanstack/react-query
```

*2. use the new QueryClient*

Remove this line from your source:
`import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query"` and replace with:

```js
...
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
} from '@tanstack/react-query'
...
```

Comment: I got this error after my 4 related react-query packages got out of sync. I fixed in a similar way: uninstalling and reinstalling them at once.

(I was working with different minor v5 versions of  `@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister`, `@tanstack/react-query @tanstack/react-query-devtools`, `@tanstack/react-query-persist-client`)